# robust clustered standard error from pooled regression in R?

Tags: r, dataset, regression, cluster-analysis, imputation

I have used multiple imputation (m=30) to impute missing values in a dataset which I am now running a regression on in R. In my final model I want to have robust clustered standard errors, but am unsure of how to do so since I am pooling the results of the 30 imputations to get my final model. Does anyone know a command I can run after I've pooled the data to get robust clustered SE? Or do I need to input something before I pool the data? I've attached a screenshot of my code and the error message below.
I am trying to follow the instructions from [this tutorial](https://francish.netlify.app/post/multiple-imputation-in-r-with-regression-output/) using the mitools package. But it looks like they only have instructions on how to apply to a single dataset from the imputation trials, whereas I hope to use the pooled regression.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It is hard to help you out with this issue as there is some information missing: could you let others know where functions like `coeftest()` and `pool()` come from? Given that they are not part of Base R, and that your screenshot does not show what was loaded, it is not  straight-forward.
Also, including the actual code rather than a screenshot would be helpful (I understand that a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/#reprex) might be tricky to create).

Comment: @stragu yes sorry for the lack of information. I've added a link which closely follows what I am trying to do that should hopefully clarify things.